# PHPStorm exclude Tests from coverage percentage

Tags: magento, phpunit, code-coverage, phpstorm

I am wondering if it is possible to configure PHPStorm to exclude the Test folder from the percentages, since my module has 100% coverage but the Test folder is bringing the overall value down to 50%.

[image: Tests bringing percentage down]

This could be unrelated, but I also have an issue where the coverage window never displays the actual coverage data, neither in the separate tab nor viewing the file itself.

[image: Empty coverage data]

Chances are I have mis-configured something, or it is something to do with my project setup (composer based Magento project with symlinking) but I'm banging my head against the wall a bit. Any suggestions welcome.

Update to include phpunit.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- initial phpunit configuration file, that you can modify for your project needs -->
<phpunit cacheTokens="true"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         stopOnError="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         stopOnIncomplete="false"
         stopOnSkipped="false"
         strict="false"
         stderr="true"
         verbose="false"
         bootstrap="app/code/community/EcomDev/PHPUnit/bootstrap.php">
    <listeners>
        <listener file="app/code/community/EcomDev/PHPUnit/Test/Listener.php" class="EcomDev_PHPUnit_Test_Listener"/>
    </listeners>
    <testsuite name="Magento Test Suite">
        <file>app/code/community/EcomDev/PHPUnit/Test/Suite.php</file>
    </testsuite>
    <filter>
        <blacklist>
            <!-- Exclude Magento Core files from code coverage -->
            <directory suffix=".php">app/code/core</directory>
            <!-- Exclude EcomDev_PHPUnit classes from code coverage -->
            <directory suffix=".php">app/code/community/EcomDev/PHPUnit</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">lib/EcomDev/Utils</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">lib/EcomDev/PHPUnit</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">lib/Spyc</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">lib/vfsStream</directory>
            <!-- Exclude Mage.php file from code coverage -->
            <file>app/Mage.php</file>
            <!-- Exclude template files -->
            <directory suffix=".phtml">app/design</directory>
            <!-- Exclude Varien & Zend libraries -->
            <directory suffix=".php">lib/Varien</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">lib/Zend</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">lib/Magento</directory>
        </blacklist>
    </filter>
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="var/phpunit/coverage" charset="UTF-8" yui="true" highlight="false" lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70"/>
        <log type="coverage-clover" target="var/phpunit/coverage.xml"/>
        <log type="junit" target="var/phpunit/junit.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false"/>
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

The reason I thought it might be PHPStorm is the fact that the HTML version of the coverage works perfectly, correctly excluding the Test folder.

[image: Correct coverage in HTML view]

Comment: "Coverage Summary: null" -- Yes -- **symlinks** or code tested is located outside of the project root. File names in code coverage .xml file **must** match those that IDE works with. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-11852 and related.

Comment: *"Test (0% files)"* -- 1) configure whitelist  in your phpunit.xml as per suggestion from Sebastian; 2) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-27434 -- hopefully one day PhpStorm itself will be excluding files from test source folders automatically.

Comment: Thank you LazyOne, so it looks like I'm going to have to live with the percentage showing 0% in Projects view, until they resolve that issue? At least I know it's not just me! I've tried copying the files so they are physically there rather than symlinks but same result. Even modifying the coverage.xml result seems to have no impact. I'll keep messing with it, thank you for your response.

Comment: From following your links through to other topics I came across one issue where the .idea folder was in a different location. For me this is also the case, I have .idea elsewhere (so as not to need gitignore) in a separate path to my actual files. I wonder if PHPStorm requires the .idea to be in the actual project root with all coverage files as children. I created a new PHPStorm project on top of the same project (so as to add the .idea folder) and ran coverage, and the window is now populated! So I guess I should change my .idea habits... not sure why I should need to though :)

Comment: *"Even modifying the coverage.xml result seems to have no impact."* 1) PhpStorm always generates separate copy of it in addition to what yo have specified in `phpunit.xml` (that's useful, for example, if user does not have `phpunit.xml`) 2) Such coverage data is cached -- simple modifying even correct file does not make IDE to reload it. Such reloading has to be done manually (by removing and then re-adding the same coverage.xml file in that "Tools | Show Code Coverage Data" screen)

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with PhpStorm. You simply need to configure a [whitelist](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html#code-coverage-analysis.including-excluding-files) for your project.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Sebastian, I have actually tried this with no luck. I have updated the original question with my config and a screenshot of the HTML coverage report, which is actually correct and lead me to believe the issue was with PHPStorm.